# Renderizar archivo js.erb luego de un fetch a action controller en Rails

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo una función con un addEventListener que ejecuta un fecth con method Post hacia un action de un controller, y al finalizar, esto debería renderizar su respectivo archivo js.erb en su carpeta en view. Pero esto no está funcionando. Le adjunto mi código.
Este es mi script para ejecutar el fetch al seleccionar un checkbox

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const checksInputs = document.querySelector('.pasajeros-programa');
  
  if (checksInputs) {
    const ruta = checksInputs.dataset.ruta;
    const cobranzaID = checksInputs.dataset.cobranza;
    
    const pasajeros = checksInputs.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    const tokenForm = document.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']").content;
    
    for (let item of pasajeros) {
      item.addEventListener('change', () => {
        let ids = Array.from(pasajeros).filter(x => x.checked)
        ids = ids.map(x => +x.value)
        fetch(ruta, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRF-Token": tokenForm,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({pasajeros: ids, cobranza_id: cobranzaID})
        }).then(res => console.log('cambio'))
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Y este es el código en el controlador.

```
  def update_pasajeros
    @programa = Programa.find(params[:id])
    len = params[:pasajeros].length - 1
    @cobranza = params[:cobranza_id]
    for pasajero in @programa.pasajeros
      pasajero.programa = nil
      pasajero.save!
    end
    
    (0..len).each do |i|
      pasajero = Pasajero.find(params[:pasajeros][i])
      pasajero.programa = @programa
      pasajero.save!
    end
    
    puts '*******************'
    puts @programa.cobranza.has_programas?
    puts @programa.cobranza.id
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'update_pasajeros'}
    end
  end
```

Esto se ejecuta bien, pero no renderiza el archivo .js.erb, aunque en mi terminal aparece este mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto está en mi archivo js.erb, sin embargo no se ejecuta nada en mi consola.

```
   console.log('se cambio')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero en tu request estás llamando con `application/json`, eso significa que tu estás esperando un json como respuesta, no un código en javascript. ¿has revisado la consola de tu explorador lo que te está retornando el request? ¿cual es su contenido y el formato de la respuesta recibida?

Comment: Me retorna un objeto, lo he colocado al final de la pregunta como imagen